# Expose a model to a template?

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a plugin which has a controller, service and a model. The model represents some fields which will be POST'd and then emailed via the service.

The controller uses an action to populate the model via the $_POST vars, which is exposed to the template for displaying validation errors:

```
$fields = BusinessLogic_EventBookingFormModel::populateModel($_POST);

if ($fields->validate()) {
    // send the email...
} else {
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'errors' => $fields->getErrors()
    ));
}
```

I'd like to expose that model to the template before it's populated, I assume via a template variable. What is standard-practise for instantiating and then managing a reference to that model? Where would the instance live? In the service perhaps?

Comment: "I'd like to expose that model to the template before it's populated" - I'm confused by that. You want to expose the model to the template before you populate it?

Comment: Yes. The model is defined but has no data in it.

Comment: Where exactly do you want this to happen?  From your controller? If so, where in the code?